# Generate a sample xml document with iterable element and namespaces from a schema

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, sample, iterable

I have an bunch of xsd which describe a document with some iterable elements. I would like to generate an sample xml document with at least 2 iteration of each iterable element and all namespace prefixes

I tried with xmlspy, it worked, but it did not generate all the namespace prefixes.

I also tried with eclipse, it generate all the namespace prefixes, but it doesn't create any iteration

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried XMLSpear? [See here](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/)

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't seem to do the job, sadly

Comment: I also tried , and seems that all namespace prefixes are included. Have you tried "Translation \ Schema to XML instance". If does not work make sure that there are `targetNamespace`.

Comment: It creates a empty XML with only the root element, and nothing in it. I need to add that one of my xsd depends on several others xsd.